# Why can't block specified string with iptables command?

Tags: iptables, filter

I want to block any packages flow into my pc which contains the string `porn`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "porn" -j DROP
```

Open my firefox and iniput keyword `porn` in google search engine,why webpages contains `porn` still been displayed?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of HTTPS.

Comment: The recommended way to block HTTP(s) traffic is to use a web proxy.